# Returning a subclass object from a parent class method

Tags: c++

Is it possible to return a subclass instance of an object inside a parent class method? What I'm trying to do is I have a Member class as parent and a Voter subclass, and I want the member to have a method to turn itself into a voter object.

Comment: its a bit backwards to make the base class aware of the subclasses. Anyhow, can you show a small example of what you want to do? (see also [mcve]).

Comment: describe your initial problem which supposed to be solved by returning subclass object, since this looks like [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Any method can return whatever type you declare, yet you can't pretend that an object created as "Member" (i.e. = new Member()) is a subclass of member; i.e. any static/dynamic/reinterpret-cast will either fail or yield undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The parent class has no way of knowing the extra methods and members of the inheriting class.

An object from child class can be casted to the parent but not the other way around.

Now depending on what you are trying to do, I'm guessing there should be a way of returning a value from the parent class that may help you build an object from the child class.
Again, it depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: look at the other answer. The parent does not need to know what members or methods the inheriting class has but still it can provide a method to return a subclass instance

Answer (score 1):

I am sometimes using something similar, typically it looks like this:

```
template<typename MemberType>
class Member
{
public:
    MemberType *asChild() { return static_cast<MemberType*>(this); }
};

class VoterA : public Member<VoterA> {};
class VoterB : public Member<VoterB> {};
```

You can put it as whatever, for example overriding `operator*` so that dereferencing `Member` yields it as the given template type. Typical usage, consider:

```
class Elections
{
public:
    void vote(VoterA obj);
    void vote(VoterB obj);
};
```

You can also make the element do the voting:

```
template<typename MemberType>
class Member
{
public:
    Member(Voter *voter) : mVoter(voter) {}

    void vote()
    {
        mVoter->vote(*static_cast<MemberType*>(this));
    } 

private:
    Voter *mVoter = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: from the question its not really clear if OP wants a cast (your answer) or some kind of conversion (creating a new `Voter` from a `Member` somehow). Your answer assumes that the `Element` actually is a `Elementype`, but given just an `Element` simply casting it to an `ElementType` is in general not correct

Comment: @user463035818 He clearly says his `Voter` is a subclass of `Member` (my original `Element`).

Comment: yes its a subclass, but if you have `Member<VoterA> x; x.asChild()->vote();` the cast will fail, or do i miss something?

Comment: @user463035818 Why would it? You are allowed to cast to yourself. `static_cast` is compile time thing.

Comment: because `x` is not a `VoterA`

Comment: @user463035818 Oh, right. That is of course programmer's responsibility to not do things like that. :-)

Comment: yes thats more or less what I was trying to say ;). It would certainly also be possible to enable `Member<VoterA> x; x.asChild()->vote();` but we dont really know what OP wants

Comment: @user463035818 One could also make use of SFINAE and `std::is_base_of` to only enable `Member` if `MemberType` is derived from it. However I find such things to be an overkill in most contexts. And of course, the OP was too vague to know the exact requirements and use case.